# How to implement google places api into Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-places-api

I am applying Google Places Api on my app and converting the Java to C# code. But I got this error.

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `JavaCast<T>` - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast%7BTResult%7D/p/Android.Runtime.IJavaObject/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Java.Lang.Object' to 'Android.Runtime.JavaDictionary'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I notice that in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161076/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-java-lang-object-to-android-runtime-javadictio), placeList's type is `JavaList`,
you should note that  `JavaList.Get(position)` return the type of `Java.Lang.Object`. You can't directly convert it to `JavaDictionary`.

`JavaList` `Get(int location)` method :

```
public class JavaList : Java.Lang.Object, System.Collections.IList, System.Collections.ICollection, IEnumerable
{
    ...
    public virtual Java.Lang.Object Get(int location);
}
```

## Solution 1 :

As @Jon Douglas said, you could use [JavaCast](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast%7BTResult%7D/p/Android.Runtime.IJavaObject/) :

```
JavaDictionary<string, string> googlePlace = placeList.Get(eachPlace).JavaCast<JavaDictionary<string, string>>();
```

## Solution 2 :

You could use `System.Linq` :

```
JavaDictionary<string, string> googlePlace = placeList.ElementAt(eachPlace);
```

#### Complete code :

```
using System.Linq;
...
private void showNearbyPlaces(JavaList<JavaDictionary<string, string>> placeList)
{
    for (int eachPlace = 0; eachPlace < placeList.Count; eachPlace++)
    {       
        JavaDictionary<string, string> googlePlace = placeList.ElementAt(eachPlace);

        string reference = googlePlace["reference"];
        double lat = System.Double.Parse(googlePlace["lat"]);
    }
}
```